# Confidence interval of a coder's skill level

Tags: confidence-interval, categorical-encoding

Suppose there is a program that looks at randomly selected fish from a river, and we hire coders to study a caught fish and mark whether the fish is female or isn't female.

As part of our quality assurance processes, I want to ensure that our coders are doing what they are supposed to do with reasonable performance. I naively define this performance in only one dimension: Given that a fish is in actual fact a female, the likelihood that the coder will code it as female (i.e., true positive rate)

I then run a test for a specific coder. I provide them with 10 female fishes (that I know are definitely female fishes), and this coder codes 7 of them as female and 3 of them as male. So this coder's performance with this sample is 70%.

Given this information, I'd like to know the 95% confidence interval of my estimate of this coder's true skill level, which I define as this coder's True Positive Rate if they had coded all the possible fish in this river.

I estimate this using a normal approximation interval, i.e.,

```
95% confidence interval
= p_sample ± z*sqrt(p_sample * (1-p_sample) / n)
= 0.7 ± 1.96*sqrt(0.7*(1-0.7)/10)
= 0.7 ± 0.284
= [41.6%, 98.4%]
```

Is this confidence interval that I calculated correct?

Comment: If I were one of these coders and valued my job, I would just code every fish as female. This would guarantee 100% "performance" according to your metric.

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right! That why I said I was naive.

Answer (score 0):

That is the confidence interval using the normal approximation which is reasonable, especially when $n$ is large (some may argue 10 is not large enough for the normal approximation to be good in this case). There are quite a few better options listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval)

The simplest would probably be the Wilson score interval which would be

$$
\dfrac{1}{1+z^2/n}\left(\hat{p} + \dfrac{z^2}{2n}\right) \pm \dfrac{z}{1+z^2/n}\sqrt{\dfrac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n} + \dfrac{z^2}{4n^2}}
$$

which in your case gives

```
p <- 0.7
n <- 10

z <- qnorm(1-0.05/2)

(1/(1 + z^2/n)) * (p + z^2/(2*n)) - (z)/(1 + z^2/n) * sqrt(p*(1-p)/n + z^2/(4*n^2))
(1/(1 + z^2/n)) * (p + z^2/(2*n)) + (z)/(1 + z^2/n) * sqrt(p*(1-p)/n + z^2/(4*n^2))
```

$(0.3967781, 0.8922087)$

Comment: Perfect, thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.